# Can someonehelp me correct the error?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, erc-20

"I have tried every which way to get the flaw to go away, I tried to debug, I have `_erc` under-scored it, I just cannot seem to put my finger on it. here is the original contract:

```
import "./MOOREToken.sol";
import "./DaiToken.sol";

contract TokenFarm {
    string public name = "TokenFarm";
    address public owner;
    ERC20 public MOOREToken;
    ERC20 public daiToken;

    address[] public stakers;
    mapping(address => uint) public stakingBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) public hasStaked;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;

constructor(address _MOOREToken, address _daiToken) public {
        MOOREtoken = ERC20(_MOOREToken);
        daiToken = ERC20(_daiToken);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function stakeTokens(uint _amount) public {
        // Require amount greater than 0
        require(_amount > 0, "amount cannot be 0");

        // Trasnfer Mock Dai tokens to this contract for staking
        daiToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        // Update staking balance
        stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;

        // Add user to stakers array *only* if they haven't staked already
        if(!hasStaked[msg.sender]) {
            stakers.push(msg.sender);
        }

        // Update staking status
        isStaking[msg.sender] = true;
        hasStaked[msg.sender] = true;
    }

        // Unstaking Tokens (Withdraw)
    function unstakeTokens() public {
        // Fetch staking balance
        uint balance = stakingBalance[msg.sender];

        // Require amount greater than 0
        require(balance > 0, "staking balance cannot be 0");

        // Transfer Mock Dai tokens to this contract for staking
        daiToken.transfer(msg.sender, balance);

        // Reset staking balance
        stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;

        // Update staking status
        isStaking[msg.sender] = false;
    }

    // Issuing Tokens
    function issueTokens() public {
        // Only owner can call this function
        require(msg.sender == owner, "caller must be the owner");

        // Issue tokens to all stakers
        for (uint i=0; i<stakers.length; i++) {
            address recipient = stakers[i];
            uint balance = stakingBalance[recipient];
            if(balance > 0) {
                MOOREtoken.transfer(recipient, balance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then here you have the error:

```
truffle(development)> truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\DaiToken.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\MOOREToken.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\TokenFarm.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\DaiToken.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\MOOREToken.sol

/C/Users/Nmlm99/MOORETokenFarm/src/contracts/TokenFarm.sol:9:5: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
    ERC20 public MOOREToken;
    ^---^
,/C/Users/Nmlm99/MOORETokenFarm/src/contracts/TokenFarm.sol:10:5: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
    ERC20 public daiToken;
    ^---^
```

Comment: It's because it is an lvalue they, must be differentiated in ex ``_Value``

Comment: Hi there. Where is the `ERC20` type defined? In one of the imported `.sol` files?

Comment: yes i believe so..

Comment: The error is that the compiler doesn't understand what the `ERC20` type is. You need to check that the `ERC20` type is defined in one of the imported contracts.